# C++ how do i make my function go in a different file, then include the function file in the main file?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void calc () {
    double num1, num2, result;
   char op;

   cout << "Enter your first number \n";
   cin >> num1;

   cout << "Now enter your second number \n";
   cin >> num2;

   cout << "And last but not least, what operator do you want to use? \n";
   cin >> op;

   if (op == '*') {
    result = num1 * num2;
   }
   else if (op == '+') {
    result = num1 + num2;
   }
   else if (op == '-' || op == '-') {
    result = num1 - num2;
   }
   else if (op == '/') {
    result = num1 / num2;
   }
   else {
    cout << "Invalid operator";
   }
   cout << "The result is " << result << endl;
}
}


int main()
{

 calc();

    //cout - console output
    //endl - end line
    //cin - console input
    // >> - input


}
```

so thats my code,  and i was hoping to get the calc() function inside a different .cpp file, and then somehow include it into the main file (it will just make the whole project look cleaner in my opinion, thats why i want to do that)

Comment: Open your C++ textbook and search for the concepts "header files" and "separate compilation".

Comment: I am afraid that i do not understand a single thing in there xd

Comment: @exdii Then I suggest you really need to buy a book on C++ which can explain these things in detail. What you are asking about is pretty fundamental to C++ programming. Book suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to move the `calc` function you just cut and paste it to a new file. The tricky part is combining the two files. To do that you create a *header file* and `#include` the header file in both your cpp files. The header file contains a *declaration* of the function. This is how the main file knows about the function in the other file. Here's how the header file might look, I'm assuming that you are going to call the file `calc.h`.

```
#ifndef CALC_H
#define CALC_H

void calc(); // function declaration (aka function prototype)

#endif
```

The `CALC_H` stuff is an *include guard*, look that up, it would take too long to explain here.

Then as I said you just put

```
#include "calc.h"
```

at the top of both your cpp files.

Comment: Both of my cpp files?????? I need 2 cpp files???? Im so confused. Ik that one of them is the main file, but what do i put in the second, just this? :
`#include "calc.h"`
`// the funtion here`
???

Comment: OK, THANK YOU SO SO MUCH! It actually works!

Comment: @exdii Glad to help. So in the end you should have three files called (for instance) main,cpp, calc.cpp and calc.h. main.cpp has your `main` function, calc.cpp has your `calc` function and calc.h is as described above.

Comment: @exdii Usually you declare a function `func()` in func.h and you create the body of the function in func.cpp . It isn't necessary, but that's how you'll usually see this type of stuff being made

Comment: @H-005 ok, uhm sure?

Answer (score 0):

You can always define the function in a Header file and then include that header file in your main program. You can learn all things about Multiple Files Programs from here [Multiple Code Files Programs in C++](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/programs-with-multiple-code-files/comment-page-4/)